# Cross Compile Opencv example for wandboard

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to cross-compile an example of OpenCV 2.4.3 executing this:

```
 arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ main.cpp -o test1 `pkg-config opencv --libs` `pkg-config opencv --cflags`.
```

It returns the following error:

```
 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already got the OpenCV libs compiled for ARM on an image using yocto project.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly looks that you are using an incorrect binary for the platform. Seems your compiler is for ARM but `libopencv_calib3d.so` is an x86 binary.

Check using

```
$ file /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
```

Just point to the cross compiled ARM binary.